# Sidekiq with multiple instances with different queue using same redis server

Tags: sidekiq, upstart

Recently had to prioritize my Sidekiq queues (before I was using only the default queue).
so, i thought of using reserved queues as per https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#reserved-queues

**config/sidekiq.yml contents**:

```
---
:concurrency: 25
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
```

**config/sidekiq_critical.yml contents**:

```
---
:concurrency: 10
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  - critical
```

**in development environment**, 
I can able to start 2 side instances with different config files as below

```
sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_critical.yml
```

I can able to see both sidekiq instances with different queues in sidekiq ui

I don't know how to run similar way in production environment.
For production we are using similar as of mentioned in https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart

**sidekiq.conf contents**

```
script
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  sudo -i -u ec2-deploy
  cd path/to/app
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_critical.yml
EOT
end script
```

But i can able to see only one instance of sidekiq is running with **config/sidekiq.yml** queues.

Please help how to do run two sidekiq instances with different config files in the same server

Answer (score 3):

You'd create a sidekiq2.conf.  Or sidekiq-critical.conf.  Or any name you want.

Comment: I have created another sidekiq configuration as mentioned **sidekiq-critical.conf**. 
But still only one sidekiq instance is running as per configuration in **config/sidekiq.yml**.  
  i am using workers.conf as mentioned in [https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart)

Do i need to make any changes in **workers.conf**?

Comment: Thanks Mike Perham.Got the issue with workers.conf file.. Made changes and working fine.